# How to prove a numerical identity?

Tags: expression-test, convolution, testing-and-verification

Let be a function power function

```
f[s_, r_] := Piecewise[{{s^r, s >= 0}, {0, True}}];
```

And its convolution

```
Conv[s_, r_] := Sum[f[k, r]*f[s - k, r], {k, -Infinity, +Infinity}];
```

**Proposition 1.** Let be a real coefficients $A_{m,j}$ defined as follows

```
A[n_, k_] := 0
A[n_, k_] := (2 k + 1)*Binomial[2 k, k]*
   Sum[A[n, j]*Binomial[j, 2 k + 1]*(-1)^(j - 1)/(j - k)*
     BernoulliB[2 j - 2 k], {j, 2 k + 1, n}] /; 2 k + 1 <= n
A[n_, k_] := (2 n + 1)*Binomial[2 n, n] /; k == n;
```

Then for every $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an identity,

$$n^{2m+1}+1=\sum_{r=0}^{m}A_{m,r}\mathrm{Conv}_r[n], \ n>0 \ \tag1$$
where $\mathrm{Conv}_r[n]=(f_{r}*f_{r})[n]=\sum_{t}f_r(t)f_r(n-t)$.

Expression $(1)$ is implemented in Mathematica as folows

```
MainIdentity[m_, n_] := Sum[A[m, r]*Conv[n, r], {r, 0, m}];
```

And numerically it is equal to $n^{2m+1}$ for any naturals $m,n$, for example the tabular arrangement

```
n = 3; Table[MainIdentity[m, n], {m, 0, 11}]
```

gives

```
{4, 28, 244, 2188, 19684, 177148, 1594324, 14348908, 129140164}
```

Which is set of $3^{2m+1}+1, \ m=0,1,2,3.. \ $. But when the condition is checked by mathematica with `==` operator,

```
FullSimplify[MainIdentity[m, n], Assumptions -> n > 0] == 
 First@FullSimplify[n^(2 m + 1) + 1, Assumptions -> n > 0]
```

it gives `False`.

---

**Question 1:** Is there any other methods of comparison, so we can verify the formula $(1)$ ?

**Question 2:** Execution time of the Mathematica implementation of $(1)$ is very slow, can we optimaze the solution in order to decrese exec. time ?

Comment: An important question: What is `0^0` for you?

Comment: For Q1 you can use `PossibleZeroQ` to check if the difference between the expressions is zero: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html

Comment: What's the purpose of `First` in `[...] == First@FullSimplify[n^(2 m + 1) + 1, Assumptions -> n > 0]`. Not that it returns `1`!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think now it is common agreement that $0^0 = 1$, I prefer to reffer it to Knuth's Concrete mathematics. Concerning `First` I dont really know Mathematica well, so I just entered my function into the pattern I found in one of my previous questions here

Comment: @Roman `PossibleZeroQ` also gives false

Comment: When `n` or `k` is not numerical, the conditions `2 k + 1 <= n` and `k == n` are not evaluated and `A[n,k]` evaluates to the first, unconditioned definition of `A` which is `0`. So in total, your definition of `A` is not appropriate for symbolic evaluation.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher may be can we introduce some condition to the checking, so it will check only values $[0, n]\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Towards Question 2: Make it a finite sum in `Conv`. Indeed, there are only finitely many nonzero summands. Or better use `Dot`.

```
f2[s_, r_] := s^r UnitStep[s];
Conv2[s_, r_] := #.Reverse[#] &[f2[Range[0, s], r]]

m = 10;
aa = Outer[Conv, Range[0, m], Range[1, m]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
bb = Outer[Conv2, Range[0, m], Range[1, m]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
aa == bb
```

> 11.0072
>
> 0.001253
>
> True

Comment: As I see you use `==` on the values of Timings or ? Still, the main aim is to show that `MainIdentity[m_, n_] == n^(2m+1)+1`.

Comment: How to check identity $(1)$ in main question ?

Comment: I applied `==` to the outputs of `Conv` and `Conv2` in order to check that the produce the same results. The timings are supposed to show you that the new definition of `Conv` and `f` lead to 10000-times faster evaluation for numeric input.